# Where would FTP alias go into in .NET FTP connections

Tags: .net

I have a current connection method

```
    ftp ftpClient = new ftp(@"ftp://testftp/", @"username", @"password", false);
string[] dirlist = ftpClient.directoryListSimple("/");
            foreach (var x in dirlist) { Console.WriteLine(x); }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

This is the code for the FTP class's directory list

```
      public class ftp
    {
        private string host = null;
        private string user = null;
        private string pass = null;
        private FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
        private FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
        private Stream ftpStream = null;
        private int bufferSize = 2048;
        private bool enableSSL = true;
/* List Directory Contents File/Folder Name Only */
    public string[] directoryListSimple(string directory)
    {
        try
        {
            /* Create an FTP Request */
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + directory);
            /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            /* When in doubt, use these options */
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = false;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            /* EnableSSL if required, most times false */
            ftpRequest.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
            /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
            ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
            StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
            /* Store the Raw Response */
            string directoryRaw = null;
            /* Read Each Line of the Response and Append a Pipe to Each Line for Easy Parsing */
            try { while (ftpReader.Peek() != -1) { directoryRaw += ftpReader.ReadLine() + "|"; } }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            /* Resource Cleanup */
            ftpReader.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpResponse.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
            /* Return the Directory Listing as a string Array by Parsing 'directoryRaw' with the Delimiter you Append (I use | in This Example) */
            try { string[] directoryList = directoryRaw.Split("|".ToCharArray()); return directoryList; }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Return an Empty string Array if an Exception Occurs */
        return new string[] { "" };
    } 
}
```

I then try to run a directory list, which works perfect in a test setting.
However when I go to with one of our partners, I get the **530 Not Logged In**
I tested in Chrome and it logged in fine and showed the Directory List
I tried with SSL, without, Active, Passive to no avail
THe last thing I can think of is they provided an Alias, but I can't figure out where it would go. On google they said to do testftp|alias but that didn't work due to URI formatting
Any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer,
For some reason, it was attempting to establish an SSL connection even though I had set it to false. Commenting out that line has allowed connection